# Unable to receive non-committed Kafka messages again

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I have this Kafka consumer I implemented using Spring:

```
public class MyKafkaConsumer<T> implements AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, T> {
   private final ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, T> container;

    public MyKafkaConsumer(ConsumerFactory<String, T> consumerFactoryry) {
       ContainerProperties prop = new ContainerProperties("mytopic");
       prop.setGroupId("mygroupid");
       prop.setMessageListener(this);
       prop.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
       this.container = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory, prop);
    }

   @Override
   public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, T> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        // Just log the message, but don't acknowledge
   }
}
```

Kafka has these 2 properties configured:

```
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
enable.auto.commit = false
```

As I don't call acknowledgment.acknowledge(), I would expect the offset not being committed. I would also expect to receive the same message multiple times, but that doesn't happen. It only happens to receive the same message when I restart the entire application. Why is that? Shouldn't I keep receiving the same message multiple times?

I know for sure the offset is not committed, because I receive the message again when I restart the application. So, what's else is going on?

I noticed that if I throw an exception in the "onMessage" method, then I actually keep receiving the same message multiple times. What's the difference in that case? isn't the offset non-committed in the same way in both cases?

Comment: Pretty sure that behavior is built into the Consumer, based on this, check out the "Offsets and Consumer Position" section  https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: It makes sense... but then what's different when I throw exception? Because in that case I keep receiving the same message

Comment: Odds are that the Consumer class you're being provided updates the `position` value after it calls `onMessage`, so in the case of an uncaught exception in `onMessage`, the internal position wouldn't be updated.  (normally I'd look at code to confirm this, but havent found the right source yet).  If you want to only receive the message once, even when you got an exception during processing, you could add a try/catch inside `onMessage` that doesn't re-throw.  In an ideal world, you'd toss the offending message in another queue for manual handling, or log it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The default is BATCH, commit offset after record processing finishes,  this is why you do not get the messages again

BATCH: Commit the offset when all the records returned by the poll() have been processed

---

Committing Offsets
Several options are provided for committing offsets. If the enable.auto.commit consumer property is true, Kafka auto-commits the offsets according to its configuration. If it is false, the containers support several AckMode settings (described in the next list). The default AckMode is BATCH. Starting with version 2.3, the framework sets enable.auto.commit to false unless explicitly set in the configuration. Previously, the Kafka default (true) was used if the property was not set.

The consumer poll() method returns one or more ConsumerRecords. The MessageListener is called for each record. The following lists describes the action taken by the container for each AckMode (when transactions are not being used):

RECORD: Commit the offset when the listener returns after processing the record.

BATCH: Commit the offset when all the records returned by the poll() have been processed.

TIME: Commit the offset when all the records returned by the poll() have been processed, as long as the ackTime since the last commit has been exceeded.

COUNT: Commit the offset when all the records returned by the poll() have been processed, as long as ackCount records have been received since the last commit.

COUNT_TIME: Similar to TIME and COUNT, but the commit is performed if either condition is true.

MANUAL: The message listener is responsible to acknowledge() the Acknowledgment. After that, the same semantics as BATCH are applied.

MANUAL_IMMEDIATE: Commit the offset immediately when the Acknowledgment.acknowledge() method is called by the listener